# How to convert a formula in a string to value inside a function, Is this possible

Tags: sql

So far i have used this code in side the function, and it doesn't work properly. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @result float

SET @sql = N'set @result = ' + @Word
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result float output', @result out
RETURN @result
```

Comment: Word will take the string formular, ex : ('1+2-1')

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That code's far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: I have tried your code in SQL server , and it works perfectly .. can you please redefine your problem by adding something like sample input output may be..and the DBMS tag..

Comment: The problem is this code segment is not working inside a function. It returns a error "Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function"

Comment: This is Sql server 2012